# WSL - Is it possible to access and manipulate a virtual Linux machine with WSL?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

Is it possible to access and manipulate a virtual Linux machine with WSL?

For example, if I installed a Linux virtual machine (LVM) with VirtualBox when Windows 10 is the host machine, could I access it and change files with it with the Windows WSL?

Thanks,

Comment: In WSL, type `ssh <yourlinuxvm>`. Of course, you need to make sure network and ssh server is configured correctly.

Comment: Now after this comment I could publish this expandedly in an answer but please do so yourself. Allow me to give you that honor after noting that (I ssh daily but didn't think of this lol as I thought the WSL dev team might give a more automatic way via some kind of specially constructed interface, though looking more deeply, construction of such interface is totally redundant by any speculation and ssh is the most stable way to go).

Comment: Its' my pleasure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WSL, you can type `ssh <remote_linux_vm>`, using WSL as standard SSH client.

Linux VM's network should be configured to accept external request. Bridge should work, while NAT doesn't.